# PostgreSQL planner is choosing hash/merge join over faster nested loop

Tags: postgresql, nested-loops, postgresql-performance

I have two tables `tbl11` and `tbl2` with 700M and 900M rows respectively.
When I have one value to find in 'tbl1' and join it with `tbl2`, the optimizer chooses a nested loop join and did an Index scan and ran faster.But when I try to do the same for 500 values, it chooses hash and merge joins and runs forever. But when I set `enable_hashjoin` and `enable_mergejoin` to `off`, it chooses a nested loop join and runs like a charm.

Why did PostgreSQL not choose the nested loop join as it runs faster in this case?

```
**Query plan with hash and merge turned off:**

Sort  (cost=598690203560.58..598690203860.89 rows=120124 width=336)
Sort Key: cte_fl3_837_835_all.submitintchgtime_isa_09_10 DESC, cte_fl3_837_835_all.submitclaimid_2300_clm_01 DESC
  CTE cte_my_claims
   ->Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..139.48 rows=4734 width=32)
       ->Seq Scan on test_fl3_837p_claims  (cost=0.00..31.89 rows=789 width=13)
          ->Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=6 width=3)
              ->Seq Scan on all_market_claim_id_manipulation  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=3)
  CTE cte_fl3_837p_clm
    ->Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..59755293.38 rows=17689084 width=48)
          ->CTE Scan on cte_my_claims clml  (cost=0.00..94.68 rows=4734 width=32)
          ->  Index Scan using pidx_fl3_837p_segments_clm_id on fl3_837p_segments p837  (cost=0.56..12585.19 rows=3737 width=48)
           Index Cond: (element_01 = clml.part_claim_id)


**With Hash and Merge On:**

Sort  (cost=7081980295.88..7081980596.19 rows=120124 width=336)
Sort Key: cte_fl3_837_835_all.submitintchgtime_isa_09_10 DESC, cte_fl3_837_835_all.submitclaimid_2300_clm_01 DESC
  CTE cte_my_claims
    ->Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..139.48 rows=4734 width=32)
         ->Seq Scan on test_fl3_837p_claims  (cost=0.00..31.89 rows=789 width=13)
          ->Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=6 width=3)
               ->Seq Scan on all_market_claim_id_manipulation  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=3)
  CTE cte_fl3_837p_clm
    ->Merge Join  (cost=26624634.82..26941108.79 rows=17689084 width=48)
          Merge Cond: (clml.part_claim_id = p837.element_01)
          ->Sort  (cost=383.66..395.50 rows=4734 width=32)
                Sort Key: clml.part_claim_id
                ->CTE Scan on cte_my_claims clml  (cost=0.00..94.68 rows=4734 width=32)
        ->Materialize  (cost=26624251.16..26717290.79 rows=18607927 width=48)
             ->Sort(cost=26624251.16..26670770.98 rows=18607927 width=48)
                Sort Key: p837.element_01
                ->Bitmap Heap Scan on fl3_837p_segments p837  (cost=482386.53..22660154.99 rows=18607927 width=48)
                    Recheck Cond: ((segment_type)::text = 'CLM'::text)
                     ->Bitmap Index Scan on pidx_fl3_837p_segments_clm_series_id  (cost=0.00..477734.55 rows=18607927 width=0)
```

Comment: Please read [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) so that you know how you can edit the question to add information that enables us to help you.

Comment: is the database recently vacuumed?

Comment: Yes, I did vacuum analyze on  all the tables being used in this query

Comment: I tried my best in formatting.Thanks

Comment: It seems planner is mainly misestimating:

Comment: It seems planner is mainly misestimating:

 ->Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..59755293.38 rows=17689084 width=48)

vs

->Merge Join  (cost=26624634.82..26941108.79 rows=17689084 width=48)

It estimates merge will be twice as fast as index scan alternative, I'd suggest using analyze on both tables (not vacuum analyze) and if it is not helping reindexing tables.

If nothing helps you will need to optimize planner costs to adapt to your box, costs for planner are quite standard and might not be accurate for most systems.

Comment: When u say " It estimates merge will be twice as fast as index scan alternative," what do u mean as Merge cost is higher than the Nested as above?